# What is a good way to create a JavaScript array with big indices?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

I'm making a web app where a user gets data from PHP, and the data consists of MySQL rows, so I want to save the used ones in a global variable, something like a buffer, to prevent extra AJAX requests.

I'm doing this right now :

```
window.ray = []; // global variable
$(function(){
   data = getDataWithAjax(idToSearch);
   window.ray[data.id] = data.text;
});
```

but when the id is big, say 10 for now, `window.ray` becomes this :

```
,,,,,,,,42
```

so it contains 9 unnecessary spots. Or does it? Is it only visible when I'm doing `console.log(window.ray);`

If this is inefficient, I want to find a way like PHP, where I can assign only indices that I want, like :

```
$array['420'] = "abc";
$array['999'] = "xyz";
```

Is my current way as efficient as PHP, or does it actually contain unnecessary memory spots?

Thanks for any help !

Comment: just so you know, an array with "unnecessary spots" is called a sparse array. I understand that you're worried about performance, but, just for your knowledge, when a large portion of an array is sparse, the optimizer implements it in a more memory-efficient way to use less RAM. However, sparse arrays, thanks to this special mechanism, are actually slower to access than normal arrays

Comment: @Markasoftware Thanks ! I have heard the term before, now I exactly know what it means :D Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an object instead of an array.  The object will let you use the id as the key and be more efficient for non-sequential id values.

```
window.ray = {}; // global variable
$(function(){
   data = getDataWithAjax(idToSearch);
   window.ray[data.id] = data.text;
});
```

You can then access any element by the id:

```
var text = window.ray[myId];
```

Comment: @CengizFrostclaw - yes, you can store anything in an object, including another object.  The key that you are indexing it by needs to be a unique string though, but as long as that's still the id, it would work.  I don't understand what you mean by the second question.  If you store an object instead of the text like you store your `data` object, then you can access `window.ray[myId].text`.

Comment: The second question was about syntax. But it's not important. It works this way, so I'll stick with it :)

Comment: If all access is by direct property name (i.e. not using a for loop), then it doesn't make any difference whether an Object or Array is used.

Answer (score 0):

If you are assigning values directly by property name, then it doesn't make any difference in terms of performance whether you use an Array or an Object. The property names of Arrays are strings, just like Objects.

In the following:

```
var a = [];
a[1000] = 'foo';
```

then `a` is (a reference to) an array with length 1,001 (always at least one greater than the highest index) but it only has one numeric member, the one called `'1000'`, there aren't 1,000 other empty members, e.g.:

```
a.hasOwnProperty['999']; // false
```

Arrays are just Objects with a special, self–adjusting length property and some mostly generic methods that can be applied to any suitable object.

One feature of sparse arrays (i.e. where the numeric properties from *0* to *length* aren't contiguous) is that a for loop will loop over every value, including the missing ones. That can be avoided and significant performance gains realised by using a for..in loop and using a hasOwnProperty test, just like an Object.

But if you aren't going to use any of the special features of an Array, you might as well just use an Object as suggested by jfriend00.

Comment: I was curious about performance.  For the test I tried in Firefox and Chrome, the object seems to be about 10% faster than an array: http://jsperf.com/object-vs-array-for-performance.  In IE, the array was slightly faster.  Results may depend upon the specifics of the use.

Comment: FYI, a sequential array is 20x faster than either a sparse array or an object in Chrome.

Comment: @jfriend00—I think performance will vary greatly between implementations. The point is that there is no reason related to the specification that makes direct property access on an Array any faster or slower than on an Object, they use exactly the same algorithm. Of course in practice access may be optimised for one more than the other, but that is an implementation detail and likely has swings and roundabouts.

Comment: Yep, that's what the perf test shows.  But, the fact that the comparison between the two options varies from one browser to the next shows that they aren't all using the exact same code for a sparse array and an object.  If they were, there wouldn't be any difference at all.

Comment: Writing properties to an Array should be a tad slower as it requires a check and possible adjustment of the *length* property. The surprise (for me) is how optimised *push* seems to be in modern browsers (but that's not relevant here as it doesn't suit the OP).